# ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity in horizontal position of the DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have the DialogFragment which plays the video from the Recyclerview item.
In vertical view everything works fine, but when I am rotating a smartphone to the horizontal position or pushing full-screen button app crashes and in logs I can see this:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

I tried this:

```
public VideoEventsFragment() {
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    // handles https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17423
    if (dialog != null && getRetainInstance()) {
        dialog.setDismissMessage(null);
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

but it doesn't work